# appending new content and refreshing UITableView freezes my app for couple seconds in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

In my `Swift` app I have a `UITableView` and `UITextView`. The idea is simple, when user adds a text - it should appear at the bottom of the table view.

So I have an array of my object `SingleMessage`:

```
var messages = [SingleMessage]()
```

When user adds a text to `UITextView`, I send message with `Socket.IO` and receive it:

```
func messageArrived(_ notification: Notification) {
    if let message = (notification as NSNotification).userInfo?["message"] as? SingleMessage {
           DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
              messages.append(message)
              self.tview.reloadData()
              self.scrollToBottom()
     )}
    }
}
```

my function `scrollToBottom()` contains the following code:

```
if(self.messages.count > 0) {
        let iPath = IndexPath(row: self.tview.numberOfRows(inSection: 0)-1, section: self.tview.numberOfSections-1)
        self.tview.scrollToRow(at: iPath, at: UITableViewScrollPosition.bottom, animated: false)
    }
```

and then I have `cellForRow` function, that does a lot of stuff, like setting fonts and texts for each label, etc.

```
override func tableView(_ tview: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "chat") as! SingleCommentCell

    if let msg:SingleMessage =  self.messages[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row] as? SingleMessage {

        .
        .
        .
```

My problem is that when I type something, then presses the `send` button immediately and start typing again - the whole interface freezes for couple seconds and I don't even see the feedback from the keyboard. I think that the problem is that the table view has to be completely refreshed.

I'm using the interface above in the Chat component, so the problem occurs not only when user quickly types several messages in a row, but also when there're many incoming messages.

Is there any way of speeding up the whole interface, like for example add new cells at the bottom of the table view and avoid refreshing already existing ones?

The other functions related to my `UITableViewController` are:

```
override func tableView(_ tview: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return messages.count

}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {


    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension

}
```

Then I have:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tview.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.none
    tview.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

    tview.delegate = self
    tview.dataSource = self

    self.tview.estimatedRowHeight = 100

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ChatView.messageArrived(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: incomingMessage), object: nil)
}
```

Comment: Honest question. Why make a point of tagging this as Swift? It sounds like something **much** more broad. Nothing sounds language specific.

Comment: It's a swift question. Nothing wrong with that.

Comment: Not related, but if `messages` is obviously non-optional why do you optional bind it in `cellForRowAt`? Write simply `let msg =  self.messages[indexPath.row]` without braces. And don't get the number of rows from the (table) view, get it from the number of `messages`. And finally the `DispatchQueue` closure will not compile.

Comment: Can you only reload certain rows instead of the whole tableview? Using `- (void)reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation;` ? If you know what chat you are in, and therefor know what row you should be editing/updating?

Comment: No, it **coded** using Swift. It's about **UITableViews** and **ios**. Restricting this to Swift by tagging means two things: (1) Possible answers for proper usage of UITableView may not view it, and mostly (2) you want the answer in Swift because you can't convert an Objective-C answer that works.

Comment: Why are you using the DispatchQueue? Is that line of code running inside a closure already?

Comment: @user3766930 would you be able to edit and put your full tableviewcontroller code up?

Comment: @DonovanKing I added more code to my original question

Answer (score 1):

`reloadData` is a very expensive operation.  It rebuilds the entire table.  You are better off keeping better track of your model, using insert and delete row functions when you want to perform those operations and refresh individual rows when they change.

A good strategy for this is to keep the old model, generate the new model, then compute the set of items that were created, moved, or removed and generate individual table operations for each case.  Here is a bit of sample code:

```
- (void) setDevicesForKey: (NSString *) propertyKey
                toDevices: (NSArray *) newDevices
{
    NSArray *currentDevices = [self valueForKey: propertyKey];
    NSUInteger tableSection = [self sectionForKey: propertyKey];

    NSIndexSet *indexesOfItemsToRemove = [currentDevices indexesOfObjectsPassingTest: ^BOOL(DeviceItem * itemToCheck, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        return ![newDevices containsObject: itemToCheck];
    }];

    NSIndexSet *indexesOfItemsToAdd = [newDevices indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL(DeviceItem *itemToCheck, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        return ![currentDevices containsObject: deviceItem];
    }];

    UITableView *tableView = [self tableView];
    [tableView beginUpdates];
    {
        NSMutableArray *removeIndexPaths = [NSMutableArray array];
        [indexesOfItemsToRemove enumerateIndexesUsingBlock: ^(NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            [removeIndexPaths addObject: [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem: idx inSection: tableSection]];
        }];

        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths: removeIndexPaths withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

        NSMutableArray *insertIndexPaths = [NSMutableArray array];
        [indexesOfItemsToAdd enumerateIndexesUsingBlock:^(NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            [insertIndexPaths addObject: [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem: idx inSection: tableSection]];
        }];

        [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths: insertIndexPaths withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

        [newDevices enumerateObjectsUsingBlock: ^(DeviceItem *itemToCheck, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            if([currentDevices containsObject: itemToCheck])
            {
                NSUInteger oldIndex = [currentDevices indexOfObject: ticketToCheck];
                NSUInteger newIndex = [newDevices indexOfObject: ticketToCheck];

                if(oldIndex != newIndex)
                {
                    NSIndexPath *fromIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: oldIndex inSection: tableSection];
                    NSIndexPath *toIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: newIndex inSection: tableSection];

                    [tableView moveRowAtIndexPath: fromIndexPath toIndexPath: toIndexPath];
                }
            }
        }];

        [self setValue: newDevices forKey: propertyKey];
    }

    [tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to insert the row with `insertRows(at` rather than calling `reloadData` and scroll only if the cell is not visible.

```
func messageArrived(_ notification: Notification) {
    if let message = notification.userInfo?["message"] as? SingleMessage {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            // if the index path is created before the item is inserted the last row is self.messages.count
            let newIndexPath = IndexPath(row: self.messages.count, section: 0)
            self.messages.append(message)
            self.tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath], with: .automatic)
            if let visiblePaths = self.tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows, !visiblePaths.contains(newIndexPath) {
                self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: newIndexPath, at: .bottom, animated: false)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note:

The restriction of 8 characters for variable names is all over for more than 30 years.
Names like `tview` are hard to read. I'm using `tableView` in the code.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, I replaced my method `messageArrived` with yours and ran the code. This is how it works now: https://gfycat.com/SlushyPoshHapuku I'm writing here very quickly `one` `two` `three` `four` etc and check out how it still hangs the view :( Do you think there might be some other thing I could change? I also removed the optional binding in `cell for row` and left what you suggested in the comment earlier: `let msg = self.messages[indexPath.row]`

Comment: The hanging reason must be somewhere else and looks like a blocked main thread. If the message is received the table view row is inserted immediately.

Comment: vadian, you know, right now I commented this `if`: `if let visiblePaths = self.tview.indexPathsForVisibleRows, !visiblePaths.contains(newIndexPath) {` and now it works smooth... The only problem is that when there's a new message, then the table does not scroll. So the problem appears to be the scrolling to the bottom - maybe there's some other way of doing so?